# PayPal - Invalid Resource ID went querying the sale details via rest api using a sandbox txn_id

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

When querying the paypal sale get api I am receiving this from the sandbox. I am using a sandbox txn_id

{
  "name":"INVALID_RESOURCE_ID",
  "message":"The requested resource ID was not found",
  "information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#INVALID_RESOURCE_ID",
  "debug_id":"9daca12551fa8"
}

Am I using wrong Transaction id?

Comment: Can you post the request that you are submitting ?

Comment: @Eshan I am using the Node JS sdk and sending this. I am 100% sure that that "id" is a valid sandbox id

As well, my other paypal api calls work great to the sandbox. That's how I get the txn_id initially is due to a purchase.

`paypal.sale.get("78T15138WD425173W", function(err, payment) {
  console.log('payment: ',err,payment);
});`

Comment: I am only authorizing purchases, I am NOT capturing them. Perhaps that's part of the problem?

Comment: Capturing should not be the problem . I am not able to find anything with this correlation id. Is it very old correlation id ? Can you provide a fresh correlation id ?

Comment: Hi i am also facing issue https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK/issues/330

Answer (score 2):

When receiving an IPN it is important to notice the "transaction_entity". This value will communicate what type of API call needs to get made, there are multiple types:

```
"auth", "sale", "capture", "refund", etc.
```

While this was a "sale" the transaction itself was only authorized, therefore I had to do an authorization api call. Not a Sale API call.

Comment: Good to hear that you figured out yourself. Cheers!!